# My state will not re render with button click

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

I have a list of test items that I am trying to filter based on a button click. Currently my initial state shows a filter for test1. However, I want to update the state with an onClick from a button. I am not sure why it does not update. Can someone provide an explanation/example or point me towards a resource to help me understand this.

All code provided is snippets of the different files have. I only added these files because I reckon I am doing something wrong in one of them

This is my ToggleButtonGroup.tsx

```
import { ToggleButton } from "./ToggleButton";
import * as React from "react";
import { testType } from "../actions/buttonTypes";
import { UpdateSelectedType } from "../actions/buttonAction";
import { IToggleButtonState } from "../models/IToggleButtonState";

interface IProps {
  onUpdateToggleButtonState: typeof UpdateSelectedType;
  toggleButtonState: IToggleButtonState;
}

export class ToggleButtonGroup extends React.Component<IProps> {
  public render() {
    let tests = null;

      tests = this.props.toggleButtonState.probes.filter(
      test => test.probeType === this.props.toggleButtonState.testType
    );

    console.log(tests);
    console.log(this.props.toggleButtonState.testType);

    return (
      <div>
        <ToggleButton
          name={"Test 1"}
          toggle={true}
          handleSelectedTest={this.handleSelectedTest1}
        />

        <ToggleButton
          name={"Test 2"}
          toggle={true}
          handleSelectedProbe={this.handleSelectedTest2}
        />

        <ul>
          {tests.map(probe => (
            <li>{test.title}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }

  public handleSelectedTest1() {
    UpdateSelectedTestType(testType.test1);
  }

  public handleSelectedTest2() {
    UpdateSelectedTestType(testType.test2);

  }
}
```

This is my App.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import { ToggleButtonGroup } from "./components/ToggleButtonGroup";
import { IToggleButtonState } from "./models/IToggleButtonState";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { AppState } from "./store";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { UpdateSelectedProbeType } from "./actions/buttonAction";

interface IProps {
  onUpdateToggleButtonState: typeof UpdateSelectedTestType;
  toggleButtonState: IToggleButtonState;
}

class App extends React.Component<IProps> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ToggleButtonGroup
          toggleButtonState={this.props.toggleButtonState}
          onUpdateToggleButtonState={this.props.onUpdateToggleButtonState}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => ({
  toggleButtonState: state.toggle
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => {
  return {
    onUpdateToggleButtonState: bindActionCreators(
      UpdateSelectedTestType,
      dispatch
    )
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

This is my toggleButtonReducer.ts

```
import {
  ToggleActionTypes,
  TOGGLE_TEST_TYPE,
  TestType
} from "../actions/buttonTypes";
import { IToggleButtonState } from "../models/IToggleButtonState";
import { dbTests } from "../actions/buttonAction";

const initialState: IToggleButtonState = {
  testType: testType.test1,
  test: dbTests,
};

export function toggleButtonReducer(
  state = initialState,
  action: ToggleActionTypes
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_TEST_TYPE:
      return {
        ...state,
        testType: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

This is my buttonAction.ts

```
export function UpdateSelectedTestType(
  testType: TestType
): ToggleActionTypes {
  return {
    type: TOGGLE_TEST_TYPE,
    payload: testType
  };
}
```

This is my ToggleButton.tsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
interface IProps {
  name: string;
  toggle: boolean;
  handleSelectedTest(): void;
}

export class ToggleButton extends React.Component<IProps> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSelectedTest = this.handleSelectedTest.bind(this);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleSelectedTest}>{this.props.name}</button>
    );
  }

  handleSelectedTest() {
    if (this.props.handleSelectedTest) this.props.handleSelectedTest();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ToggleButtonGroup` is not connected to redux meaning the calls to `UpdateSelectedTestType` are not affecting the redux store, this is okay as you are passing the redux action `onUpdateToggleButtonState`. Considering this structure, you need to update these functions:

```
public handleSelectedTest1 = () => {
    this.props.onUpdateToggleButtonState(testType.test1);
}

public handleSelectedTest2 = () => {
    this.props.onUpdateToggleButtonState(testType.test2);
}
```

Comment: New Redux, I'm not quite sure what you mean. If I do the way you have it now. I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'onUpdateToggleButtonState' of undefined` as well as in toggleButton.tsx which probably stems from the first error: `handleSelectedProbe() {
    if (this.props.handleSelectedProbe) this.props.handleSelectedProbe();
 }`

Comment: I added the `toggleButton.tsx` to the question

Comment: This is occurring as you cannot access this.props from an unbound function. You can update your functions as per my edit of use bind()

Comment: It seems like my solution worked for you, if you are confused as to why I would suggest reading up on [redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/core-concepts) and the use of dispatch() or bindActionCreators as well as [bind](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html)